# expressing a quadratic map as a complex map

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, representation-theory, quadratic-forms

Are there any known criterion when a real quadratic mapping $ Q:\mathbb{R}^{2n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n} $ can be expressed as a complex quadratic map $ Q:\mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: For $n=1$, the criterion is the Cauchy–Riemann equations. It works for all polynomial maps, not just quadratic ones.

Comment: thanks, aren't those about differentiabilty though? What about $n=2$?

Comment: Polynomials are differentiable.  Conversely, if you have an infinite power series in the complex numbers it can't become a polynomial when you view it as a function of the real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 0):

Two polynomials agree on $\mathbb{R}^n$ iff they're the same polynomial, so if you have a polynomial $f(x_1,y_1,\ldots,x_n,y_n)$ then it's enough to consider the restriction

$$g(x_1,\ldots,x_n) := f(x_1,0, x_2,0,\ldots,x_n,0)$$

to the real axis, and then check if

$$g(x_1+y_1 i, \ldots, x_n + y_n i) = f(x_1,y_1,\ldots,x_n,y_n)$$

Comment: If I have, for example a quadratic map $Q: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ s.t. $Q(v)=(x^2-y^2,y^2-z^2,z^2-t^2,zt+xy), v \in R^4$ how do I use the above to perform the checking?

Comment: I'm not sure what order you mean for those to be in, but for example let's check if
$$\bigg((x^2 - y^2) + (y^2 - z^2)i, \; (z^2 - t^2) + (zt+xy)i\bigg)$$
is a polynomial function of $\xi:= x + i y$ and $\zeta := z + i t$.  If it is, then restricting to real values of $\xi, \zeta$ that's $(x^2 - i z^2, z^2)$, so the polynomial would have to be $(\xi^2 - i \zeta^2, \zeta^2)$.  Expanding this in terms of $x,y,z,t$ we see that it's not equal to the polynomial above.